# Why my images become blurred ? Animation with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, animation, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I tried to set responsive my animation page and for this, now I use a ConstraintLayout.

I meet a problem when i run the application, images become blurred and i don't know why

I want animate two images in this activity, the plugger (chargeur) and the logo.

XML Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AnimationStayPlugActivity"
android:background="@drawable/fond_ecran_gs"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_merci"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingHorizontal="30dp"
    android:text="SomeText"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.086" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/plugger"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/chargeur_ok"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.150"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tel_w_background"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/tel_with_background_ok"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1.2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tel_w_background"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the Java Code in the method onCreate(),
I don't want change content in my activity, i want just move the plugger from the bottom to the top direction with a TranslationY and rotate the logo in himself

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anim_stay_plug);

    mTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_merci);
    mTelephone = findViewById(R.id.tel_w_background);
    mLogo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
    mChargeur = findViewById(R.id.plugger);

    mLogo.animate().rotation(360).setDuration(4000);
    mChargeur.animate().translationY(-(5/100)).setDuration(3000);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AnimationStayPlugActivity.this, AnalysisActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 5500L);
}
```

If someone have an idea..

Comment: did you check image size? i think your blurred issue is size issue.

Comment: i haven't the problem with Relative Layout.. use mipmap folders for any dimensions is not enough? @ST

Comment: using mipmap folders can make several images for many dimentions. but if image size is 64 X 64, and imageview size is 128 X 128, it make blurred. if you want to solve blurred issue, you have to make image to vector.